# Filter in DotNetCoreCLI task is not working properly

Tags: yaml, xunit, dotnetcorecli

I have a strange problem with DotNetCoreCLI@2 task. I am trying to add filter in the arguments, so only specific tests can run. I am using xUnit and Trait attribute for the goal.

```
[Trait("Category", "UnitTest")]
```

Task:

```
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Run unit tests
          inputs:
            command: test
            projects: '**/*.Tests.csproj'
            publishTestResults: true
            arguments: >-
              -c $(buildConfiguration)
              --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
              -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=cobertura
              --filter Category=UnitTest
```

But when I change/rename the attribute name, its still find and run the tests.
Example:

```
[Trait("Category", "NotUnitTest")]
```

When I run dotnet test command localy, the filtration works. And when I change/rename the atribute, no test is run (as expected).

```
dotnet test --filter Category=UnitTest
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use quotation marks.
`--filter "Category=UnitTest"`